# AIR App can't capture mouse event & can't show context menu

Tags: air, flash, contextmenu, mouseevent

I'm building a AIR application and I need a custom context menu.

My Problem is: There is no context menu in my application!

I searched for long while. Most people want to disable context menu, but I want to enable it. I know how to generate a context menu, but I can't even see the build in context menu.

The reason might be: My swf application cann't capture mouse event.

Anyone know the reason? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
                        creationComplete="initApp()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private function initApp():void {
                var ctxMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                var clsitem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Close");
                var edititem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Edit");
                var otheritem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Etc.");
                clsitem.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,closeApp);
                ctxMenu.customItems.push(clsitem,edititem,otheritem);
                this.contextMenu = ctxMenu;
            }
            private function closeApp(event:Event):void {
                this.close();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Panel width="200" height="300">

    </mx:Panel>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

[image]